# Sniffing Google Dashboard trafic to reproduce in a script

Tags: ruby, http, networking, http-headers

So I'm trying to sniff the HTTP requests in Google Analytics dashboards so that I can write an automated script to export the data to CSV. (Quick aside: if anyone knows how I can simply export the data to something other than a PDF in dashboard view, it would help me greatly.)

Anyway, I've sniffed the traffic, and am trying to make a request to one of the endpoints I'll need to hit. I use the following code to do so:

```
response = RestClient.post('https://analytics.google.com/analytics/web/getPage?id=dashboard&did=sniffed_id&ds=sniffed_ds&cid=layout-1456438532954&clientDashboardVersion=sniffed_version&hl=en_US&authuser=3', { 
:Host => 'analytics.google.com',
:'X-GAFE4-XSRF-TOKEN' => 'sniffed_token',
:'Galaxy-Ajax' => 'true',
:Accept => '*/*',
:'Proxy-Connection' => 'keep-alive',
:'Accept-Language' => 'en-us',
:'Accept-Encoding' => 'gzip, deflate',
:'Content-Type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8',
:'Origin' => 'https://analytics.google.com',
:'Content-Length' =>  '56',
:'User-Agent' =>  'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_4) AppleWebKit/601.5.17 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/9.1 Safari/601.5.17',
:'Referer' => 'https://analytics.google.com/analytics/web/?authuser=3',
:'Connection' => 'keep-alive',
:'Cookie' => 'sniffed_cookie'
})
puts JSON.parse(response.body)
```

This is the exact request I saw in Charles, a post request to that URL with those headers, however, when I sniff it in Charles I get all the data, when I print out the response from my script, I get simply `{"error"=>"gaia"}`

Does anyone with more knowledge of networking requests know what the difference between making the request from a script vs form a browser is? I'm not sure what I'm missing here, this is exactly copied over from my sniffed request, I can even repeat the sniffed request in Charles no issue, but when I make it from a script it fails.

Are there any other things that are sent with a request that could verify this is a script request?

P.S. - I get a 200 status code back and the exact same headers as I do in Charles, I just get a different body for some reason.

P.P.S. - Upon further inspection, I've noticed some discrepancies in the response headers, the `content-type` of the real request is `text/javascript` whereas my script request is `application/json` There's also a few headers that aren't sent back in my script response. I'm not the most knowledgeable in networking, so I don't know the implications of these discrepencies, but someone with more knowledge than me may know.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out - Google was sending the token twice, once in the headers and once in payload of the message. Adding the token to the payload solved the issue.